# Foreach loop stop after text is displayed

Tags: php, arrays, loops, directory, limit

I'm generating and showing pictures in a picture of a day sort of script. I have a gallery page for that picture of the day (that pulls from a directory). So I want to pull all the files from the directory and when it hits the current date (which is also the same as the file name IE. 20120822.jpg is what's displaying today and 20120823.jpg is what will display tomorrow). I have it looping all of the directory images and displaying them in a gallery, but I want the loop to stop after the current date so we don't show or load the future images. Here is my code.. I'm sure I'm just doing something silly..

```
 <?PHP
   // filetypes to display
        $imagetypes = array("image/jpeg", "image/gif");
 ?>
 <?PHP

   function getImages($dir)
   {
     global $imagetypes;

    // array to hold return value
     $retval = array();

     // add trailing slash if missing
     if(substr($dir, -1) != "/") $dir .= "/";

     // full server path to directory
     $fulldir = "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/$dir";

     $d = @dir($fulldir) or die("getImages: Failed opening directory $dir for reading");
     while(false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
       // skip hidden files
       if($entry[0] == ".") continue;

       // check for image files
       $f = escapeshellarg("$fulldir$entry");
       $mimetype = trim(`file -bi $f`);
       foreach($imagetypes as $valid_type) {
         if(preg_match("@^{$valid_type}@", $mimetype)) {
           $retval[] = array(
            'file' => "/$dir$entry",
            'size' => getimagesize("$fulldir$entry")
           );
           break;
         }
       }
     }
     $d->close();

     return $retval;
   }
 ?>

 <?PHP
   // fetch image details
   $images = getImages("galleries/photo-of-the-day/images");
 $today = date("Ymd") . ".jpg";

   // display on page
   sort($images, SORT_REGULAR);
   foreach($images as $img ) {
 if ($img == "20120822.jpg" ) {
  break;
  } else { 
 ?>


 <div style="margin-right: 10px; float: left; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; border: 1px #CCCCCC solid;">

 <a href="<? echo $img['file']; ?>" rel="prettyPhoto" title="">

 <img class="image-gals" src="<? echo $img['file']; ?>" style="width: 260px; margin-bottom: 0px;padding: 10px; " /></a>

 <a href="<? echo $img['file']; ?>" style="font-size: 10px; padding: 3px 10px 10px 10px;">Download</a>

 </div>
 <? 
 }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: So what is happening when you run the code? Does it not show any images? All the images? Just today's?

Comment: after the foreach loop inside the while, just check the file name against today's date. if they match, just add a `break;` statement to stop the while loop.

Comment: `break` usually works for me when I want to break out of a loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is where you're populating your `$images` array:

```
$retval[] = array(
    'file' => "/$dir$entry",
    'size' => getimagesize("$fulldir$entry")
);
```

But when you compare them, you're doing this:

```
foreach($images as $img ) {
    if ($img == "20120822.jpg" ) {
```

`$img` will contain an array. You'll need to check `$img['file']`, and that also has the directory name in, so it won't match just the image name.